# Generating combinatorial string from map

Tags: go, recursion, depth-first-search

I have a map as such:

```
// map[int]          position in string
// map[rune]bool     characters possible at said position
func generateString(in map[int]map[rune]bool) []string { 
    // example: {0: {'A':true, 'C': true}, 1: {'E': true}, 2: {'I': true, 'X': true}}
    result := []string{"AEI", "AEX", "CEI", "CEX"} // should generate these
    return result
}
```

The difference with all possible permutations is that we are specifying which permutations are possible by index and I think that's the real head-breaker here.

Comment: 1) Suppose you have `prevRes`, a possible string of length `n`, and `mapNow`, a `map[rune]bool` that specifies what is possible at index `n`, can you figure out how to generate all possible string of length `n+1`, with `prevRes` as prefix?

Comment: 2) Suppose you are given with task only with `n=1`, can you easily generate all possible strings?

3) Given the solution of 1) and 2), can you combine it and solve this problem?

Comment: If it helps, the signature can also be: func generateString(in [][]rune) []string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to convert `map[int]map[rune]bool` to `[]map[rune]bool` since `map` iteration isn't guaranteed to be sorted by key's

After that, this is a recursive approach

```golang
var res []string

func dfs(curString string, index int, in []map[rune]bool) {
    if index == len(in) {
        res = append(res, curString)
        return
    }

    for ch, is := range in[index] {
        if !is { // I assume booleans can be false
            return
        }
        dfs(curString+string(ch), index+1, in)
    }
}
```

and we can call it with `dfs("", 0, arr)` where `arr` is given `map` converted to `slice` and answer will be in `res` variable

Comment: booleans can't be false, I should have added that, thank you for pointing this out. The signature could also be "func generateString(in [][]rune) []string" but in your solution I think you meant "dfs(curString+string(ch), index+1, in)"?

Comment: Very nice, thank you, it works: 


```
func generateStrings(curString string, index int, in [][]rune) {
 if index == len(in) {
  res = append(res, curString)
  return
 }

 for _, ch := range in[index] {
  generateStrings(curString+string(ch), index+1, in)
 }
}
```